# Jquery looping error

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation

I'm creating a slider in jquery, and i don't want to use any plugins or existente slider out there, so i'm having problem with the loop.
When i get to the last image a white space apeears and it comes back to the first image goes to the second and come back to the first again, and that repeat over and over again.

I don't know what is wrong so i was hoping if someone could help me please!
Thanks Leo!

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Slider</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="slider.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="slider">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="imagens/imagem1.jpg" alt="Imagem 1" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="imagens/imagem2.jpg" alt="Imagem 2" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="imagens/imagem3.jpg" alt="Imagem 3" />
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--<button class="prev">prev</button>
      <button class="next">next</button>-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
        @charset "utf-8";

        /* desktop */

        @media screen and (min-width: 1025px){

        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .slider{
            width:100%;
            height:400px;
            position:realtive;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider ul{
            width:300%;
            height:100%;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }

        .slider li{
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            width:33.3%;
            height:100%;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        }

        /* tablet */

        @media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1024px){
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .slider{
            width:100%;
            height:400px;
            position:realtive;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider ul{
            width:300%;
            height:100%;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }

        .slider li{
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            width:33.3%;
            height:100%;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        }

        /* phone */
        @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
            body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .slider{
            width:100%;
            height:200px;
            position:realtive;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider ul{
            width:300%;
            height:100%;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }

        .slider li{
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            width:33.3%;
            height:100%;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
        }

        .slider img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        }
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){

AutoPlay();

function AutoPlay(){
    var $img = $('img');
    var $animationSpeed = 1000;
    var $pause = 3000;
    var $totalImg = $img.length;
    var $imgWidth = $img.width();
    var $currentSlide = 1;

    setInterval(function(){
        $img.animate({'margin-left': '-='+$imgWidth}, $animationSpeed, function(){
            $currentSlide++;
            if($currentSlide > $totalImg){
                $currentSlide = 1;
                $img.css({'margin-left': 0});
            }
        }); 
    }, $pause);

} // end AutoPlay function

}); // end main function
```

Comment: I try your code... is missing a pair of parentheses })(); at the end to make it auto execute, I think...
All it does is changing the margin to the left (looks good) but it apply it to all `<img src.../>` tags so I assume you didn't post the rest of the code and it makes it hard to understand what you want to do... Please post the rest relevant code (HTML, CSS...) to put it in context.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda work if all images are the same width... other wise the animation fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var imgs = [
    "img1.jpg",
    "img2.jpg",
    "img3.jpg"

    ];
    var $img = $('#slider');
    var $imgWidth = $img.width();
    var $animationSpeed = 3000;
    var $pause = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        imgs.forEach(function(imgPath){
            $img.animate({'margin-left': '-='+$imgWidth}, $animationSpeed, function(){
                $img.attr("src", imgPath);
                $img.attr("style","'margin-left: 0");
            });
            $pause = 9000;
        });
    }, $pause, $img);   
 //*** the rest of the code....
});
```

and the image tag looks like this:

```
<img id="slider" style="width:500px;" src="img3.jpg" />
```

`style="width:500px;"` because it's the size of my biggest pic...
It has a lot to work on, but... hope it helps.